# How to find duplication values in multidimensional arrays using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an array named A as following:

```js
  {
    name: 'activityRelatedManager',
    meta: {
      title: 'Activity Related Manager',
      permissions: []
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: 'activityPublish',
        meta: { title: 'Publish Activity', permissions:[] }
      },
      {
        name: 'activityManager',
        meta: { title: 'Manage Activity', permissions:[] }
      },
      {
        name: 'activityTypeManager',
        meta: { title: ' Manage Activity Type', permissions:[] }
      },
      {
        name: 'activityLocationManager',
        meta: { title: ' Manage Activity Location', permissions:[] }
      }
    ]
  },
```

I also have an array named B like this:

```js
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "activityRelatedManager",
      "permissions": [
        "activity:publish"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "activityManager",
      "permissions": [
        "activity:index",
        "activity:show"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "activityTypeManager",
      "permissions": []
    }
]
```

What i want to do is to find the duplicated values based on 'name' key in B, and then assign the `permissions` value to A. The result should be something like this:

```js
  {
    name: 'activityRelatedManager',
    meta: {
      title: 'Activity Related Manager',
      permissions: ["activity:publish"]
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: 'activityManager',
        meta: { title: 'Manage Activity', permissions:["activity:index", "activity:show"] }
      },
      {
        name: 'activityTypeManager',
        meta: { title: ' Manage Activity Type', permissions:[] }
      }
    ]
  },
```

I think the assignment is easy, but how to find the duplication?

```js
  A.map(ele => {
    if (!ele.name || (!ele.meta && !ele.meta.permissions)) return
    for (let i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
      const element = B[i]
      if (ele.name === element.name) {
        ele.meta.permissions = element.permissions
      }
    }
    if (ele.children) {
      makePermissionRouters(B, A.children)
    }
  })
  return clientAsyncRoutes
```

I'd appreciate it if someone can help me solve this question.

Comment: Do you want your output to keep only those entries in A which have a match in B?  That's what it looks like because your sample output does not include `activityLocationManager`.  But if so, what do you want to happen if the parent node of an included node would not be included?  That is, what would happen if `activityRelatedManager` had no match in B?

Comment: @ScottSauyet The root node which in this example is 'activityRelatedManager ' always exists in the B array.

Comment: But you're asking about this recursively.  What would happen if `activityLocationManager` had children that had a match in B?  You don't include it now.  Would you include it then?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Nope, the `activityLocationManager` will not include the children that will have a match in B.

Comment: should that read "the children that **do not** have a match in B"?  Else I'm confused.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes.  "the children that do not have a match in B". Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

I would break out a utility function here, a deep version of a `filterMap` function, which takes a predicate and a transformation function and recursively filters out every level of children according to the predicate and then transforms the remaining ones with the supplied function.

You can use this by first reformatting B to be a mapping -- here we call it `perms` -- between names and lists of permissions, then calling this `deepFilterMap` with a predicate that checks if the object's name is in `perms` and a transform that sets `meta.permissions` to that value.

This version of `deepFilterMap` is specific to structures where the descendant nodes are in an array called `children`.  We could make it more generic, but that would involve another parameter to the function.  It's an interesting exercise, but perhaps overkill here.

```js
const deepFilterMap = (pred, transform) => (tree) =>
  pred (tree)
    ? {
        ... transform (tree), 
        ... (tree.children 
              ? {children: tree .children 
                                .filter (pred) 
                                .map (deepFilterMap (pred, transform))
                } 
              : {}
            )
      }
    : {}

const transform = (A, B) => {
  const perms = Object .fromEntries (B .map (
    ({name, permissions}) => [name, permissions])
  )

  return deepFilterMap (
    ({name}) => name in perms, 
    ({name, meta, ...rest}) => ({
      name, 
      meta: {...meta, permissions: perms [name]}, 
      ...rest
    })
  ) (A)
}

const A = {name: "activityRelatedManager", meta: {title: "Activity Related Manager", permissions: []}, children: [{name: "activityPublish", meta: {title: "Publish Activity", permissions: []}}, {name: "activityManager", meta: {title: "Manage Activity", permissions: []}}, {name: "activityTypeManager", meta: {title: " Manage Activity Type", permissions: []}}, {name: "activityLocationManager", meta: {title: " Manage Activity Location", permissions: []}}]};
const B = [{id: 1, name: "activityRelatedManager", permissions: ["activity: publish"]}, {id: 2, name: "activityManager", permissions: ["activity: index", "activity: show"]}, {id: 3, name: "activityTypeManager", permissions: []}];

console .log (transform (A, B))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We could, of course, inline the work of `deepFilterMap` into our main function.  Overall, we would have fewer lines of code.  But to my mind, breaking down the complexity in this manner is much more maintainable.  And you have a potentially reusable function available now.